# Is it possible to insert in mysql a combo of words and variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

**Trigger definition:**

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `user` (`ID`, `Username`, `Password`, `Online`) VALUES
(NEW.ID, "store_"NEW.ID , 'blablabla', 0);
END
```

In this trigger I have to insert as username something like store_(id of the new store).

Is it possible to do this and if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to concat/append string in SQL

a.  Use `+` operator to join the string
b. Use `Concat` function.

By using `+` operator the query would be like below.

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `user` (`ID`, `Username`, `Password`, `Online`) VALUES
  (NEW.ID, "store_" + NEW.ID , 'blablabla', 0);
END
```

By using `Concat()` function the query would be like below.

```
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `user` (`ID`, `Username`, `Password`, `Online`) VALUES
 (NEW.ID, Concat("store_",NEW.ID) , 'blablabla', 0);
END
```

Recommended option is use 'Concat' function as syntax is easier to follow, and the code looks cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Use concat function :

```
BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO user (ID, Username, Password, Online) 
     VALUES 
     (NEW.ID, CONCAT('store_',NEW.ID), 'blablabla', 0);
END
```